# print json object parent-kid relation in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child, family-tree

Lets say I have this `JSON` object:

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Simpson",
  "parent1": {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Rush",
      "parent1": {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "Fields",
          "parent1": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Dixie",
              "parent1": null,
              "parent2": null
          },
          "parent2": null
      },
      "parent2": {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "Caroline",
          "parent1": {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Ebony",
              "parent1": null,
              "parent2": null
          },
          "parent2": {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "Ramos",
              "parent1":  {
                  "id": 4,
                  "name": "Joyner",
                  "parent1": null,
                  "parent2": null
              },
              "parent2": {
                  "id": 5,
                  "name": "Candy",
                  "parent1": null,
                  "parent2": null
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "parent2": {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Cantu",
      "parent1": {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Guerra",
          "parent1": null,
          "parent2": null
      },
      "parent2": {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Melisa",
          "parent1": null,
          "parent2": null
      }
  }
}
```

and I wan't to print parent - kid relations and have every ones parents in dropdown:

```
-Simpson
    -Rush
        -Fields
            -Dixie
                null
                null
            null
        -Caroline
            -Ebony
                null
                null
            -Ramos
                 -Joyner
                     null
                     null
                 -Candy
                     null
                     null
    -Cantu
        -Guerra
            null
            null
        -Melissa
            null
            null
```

And have them like a drop down like this for instance:

```
-Simpson
        -Rush
            +Fields
```

Now I made a method to fetch `parents1` and `parents2` like this:

```
public getParents(object: any) {
    let parent1 = object?.parent1;
    if (parent1 != null) {
      this.parents1.push(parent1);
    } else {
      this.parents1.push(null)
    }

    let parent2 = object?.parent2;
    if (parent2 != null) {
      this.parents2.push(parent2);
    } else {
      this.parents2.push(null)
    }

    if (parent1 != null)
      this.getParents(parent1);
    if (parent2 != null)
      this.getParents(parent2);
  }
```

Which would return populate the arrays `parents1` and `parents2` like this:

```
0: {id: 10, name: "Rush", parent1: {…}, parent2: {…}}
1: {id: 12, name: "Fields", parent1: {…}, parent2: null}
2: {id: 1, name: "Dixie", parent1: null, parent2: null}
3: null
4: {id: 2, name: "Ebony", parent1: null, parent2: null}
5: null
6: {id: 4, name: "Joyner", parent1: null, parent2: null}
7: null
8: null
9: {id: 14, name: "Guerra", parent1: null, parent2: null}
10: null
11: null

0: {id: 13, name: "Cantu", parent1: {…}, parent2: {…}}
1: {id: 11, name: "Caroline", parent1: {…}, parent2: {…}}
2: null
3: null
4: {id: 3, name: "Ramos", parent1: {…}, parent2: {…}}
5: null
6: {id: 5, name: "Candy", parent1: null, parent2: null}
7: null
8: null
9: {id: 15, name: "Melisa", parent1: null, parent2: null}
10: null
11: null
```

Now I can easily match who is `parent1` and `parent2` (`parents1[0]` and `parents2[0]`, `parents1[1]` and `parents2[1]`...) but have no idea who is kid to whom.

I know there is a `collapse` button in `bootstrap` and that I could for example iterate through array with `*ngFor` put button for collapse in `parent` and append `id` to the next in array (child) but this will only go up to `null` and then it would get pretty complicated to do it in `component.html`

So I would like to know if someone has an idea for a easy way to this. Am I overthinking this? Thank you